# No feedback from OP to improve quality of answer

Tags: discussion, answers, bounty

Is it wrong to expect feedback from the OP?

I answered a bounty question. Not because it has bounty. But assuming people who puts bounty more than minimum are really in need of help. And the question was tagged with X509 certificate. Much fewer responses will come due to lack of experience to the answerer in field of X509.

Whenever I answer, I expect at least a downvote and comment which points my mistake so that I will get benefit from it.

Because my answer neither received upvotes nor downvotes (even a single comment). Maybe those type of rare requirements need more time to get visitor who is really in need of that. So it is clear that site can not assure feedback to the answerer.

There is nothing great to have bounty without consent of the OP. It is totally left to the OP to decide whether an answerer deserves his/her award or not. But context is not about bounty, but about the OPs responsibility. OP's response should be mandatory at least a downvote and a comment. So that answer quality can be improved.

(At least in case of a bountied question. If you put bounty it means you are in need help, and you should show some interest to read the response, try it out and give feedback)

**EDIT:**

Thanks to all. I got the clarification needed.
There is nothing wrong in expecting feedback, but **the site can't ensure feedback for an answer** or **the site can't enforce strategies that will promote giving feedback**.

Comment: The bounty setter is already penalized by having their offered rep disappear forever. It's already their loss if they don't get back to you for the rest of the bounty period. If your answer isn't getting any feedback from *anyone* during the bounty period... that's unfortunate, given that bountied questions ought to receive more attention (but I know that they suffer from a problem where the traffic doesn't really pour in until the last couple of days).

Comment: @BoltClock I totally agree. But in my case, i didn't get opportunity to know my mistakes or improve my answer if required. I don't know how future visitor will believe about answer without OP's response.

Comment: You haven't invested any differently on a bounty question than you would have on a question without a bounty. So how you respond to this should be the same as how you would respond if your answer to any other question didn't get any feedback from the asker. Granted, you might have put a little more effort than usual into your answer...

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, i haven't invested any extra time for bountied question, because Either it may be bountied or normal, I will simulate, address the issue, test it and post the answer. It will not take much time for me as i have lot of ready to test template projects in my workspace. No worries. But as SO has grown up, IMHO there was chance of improving quality of content if OPs response was there. What my answer looks like even to me is **Just a Content without any feedback**

Comment: Feedback on anything is never required, and will never be.

Comment: @Zoe It might be your opinion. [have look here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) it is clearly mentioned that **If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!**

Comment: No, that's not my opinion. That's a fact based on the way the system is built. That's still not a requirement, that's a best practice. How on Earth do you expect it to be enforced anyway? What about questions with tens of answers? It's not practical

Comment: @Zoe it is not about practical vs impractical but it looks like quality vs quantity. It is about enforcing responsibility of OP.  How on Earth do you expect running away from responsibility? Might be you have not read my question clearly. After OPs question there is no single comment by OP. Forget about tens of answer to questions which are not generic usage. My point is clear, enforce OP's responsibility if you need quality. It is not about reputation it is all about feedback.

Comment: @PraveenKumarLalasangi The bounty doesn't mean your answer isn't good enough, and has nothing to do with *"Visitor during bounty period may not able to judge answer."*, why does it matter if visitors aren't able to judge your answer? The bounty is *to get more answers*. Hence the bounty reason was *"This question has not received enough attention."*. It has nothing to do with your answer.

Comment: So we should send moderators round to peoples houses? Or take legal action in every case? What if they are dead? Do we make their relatives take over a la jarndcye vs jarndyce. Enforcing action really isn't tenable.

Comment: @NickAthePopcornKing You misunderstood question context, to make it clear edited question.

Comment: @PraveenKumarLalasangi I didn't misunderstand the question, I just wasn't answering the question, the answer to your question: *"Is it wrong to expect feedback from OP?"* is ***yes***.

Comment: @RobertLongson you made my day :D

Comment: @Nick Then you need to read [help center content](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You are saying help center is wrong.

Comment: @PraveenKumarLalasangi I didn't say it was wrong, I'm just saying you shouldn't *"expect"* it, just simply be prepared to act on it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it wrong to expect feedback from OP?

No. Yet, before I continue further on this, I want to respond first on one of your comments below your question (which I copied over exactly)

> @Zoe It might be your opinion. [have look here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) it is clearly mentioned that **If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!** [src](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390674/no-feedback-from-op-to-improve-quality-of-answer#comment736670_390674)

The how-to ask guide can be seen as a guideline. It is not a set of rules everyone has to abide by. It is *advised* that you follow it, but not mandated that you *act* on it.

Therefore, I answered your question with a "no". No, it is not wrong to expect feedback from the OP. However it is also the OP's choice to provide feedback or not. If he/she desired - granted, if he/she really has seen the answer - to not give a feedback, then it is his/her right to do so.

Same story for others that were on the question page (either as a reader or as an author of another answer), they have their choice to give some feedback on your answer as well.

Comment: More specifically, it is a set of recommendations for question *askers*, to help ensure that they get the best answer possible.  It is not a set of requirements, or things that answerers should expect. Ultimately, Stack Overflow is not a help desk. We are not here to answer questions for individual people. We're here to build a library of high-quality answers to programming questions.